# How to fetch data in simultaneous order in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table like below:

```
id----image----type  
1-----a.png----1  
2-----b.png----1  
3-----c.png----2  
4-----d.png----1  
5-----e.png----2
```

Now i want to fetch data in below order (first type 1 then type 2 then type 1 and so on):

```
1-----a.png----1  
3-----c.png----2   
2-----b.png----1   
5-----e.png----2  
4-----d.png----1
```

So how to achieve that?

I have below query so far:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE (TYPE =1 OR TYPE =2)
ORDER BY TYPE
```

Comment: what is the logic behind this ordering. Or rather what exactly is this order anyway?

Comment: i have one slideshow in which i have to display images by type. Means first image from type 1 then second image from type 2 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g

```
Select x.* from mytable x 
join mytable y on y.type =x.type and y.id <= x.id 
group by x.id 
order by count(*),x.type
```

or faster - and what I think @1000111 was trying to get at...

```
SELECT x.id
     , x.image
     , x.type
  FROM
      ( SELECT a.*
             , CASE WHEN @prev = type THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank 
             , @prev := type
          FROM your_table a
             , (SELECT @i:=0, @prev:=null) vars
         ORDER 
            BY type
             , id
      ) x
  ORDER  
     BY rank
      , type;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e27c/8

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve this with the help of `MySQL user defined variables`

```
SELECT 
t.id,
t.image,
t.type
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
     id,
     image,
     type ,
    IF(@sameType = type, @rn := @rn + 1,
        IF(@sameType := type, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
    ) AS rowNumber
    FROM your_table 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameType := 0, @rn := 0) var
    ORDER BY type , image
) AS t
ORDER BY t.rowNumber
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e27c/1/0)</kbd>

---

**Explanation:**

First sort the result set based on `type` and `image`.

Now assign a row number to each of the above sorted rows. Row number starts from `1` every time a new `type` is discovered otherwise it's incremented.

This way you will get a table `t`.

Now if you just re order the results based on `t.rowNumber` then you will get thee first row of each type, then the second and so on.

**Output:**

Running the above query on the given sample input you will get output like below:

```
| id | image | type |
|----|-------|------|
|  1 | a.png |    1 |
|  3 | c.png |    2 |
|  2 | b.png |    1 |
|  5 | e.png |    2 |
|  4 | d.png |    1 |
```